# javac not finding another compiled class in current folder

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using OpenJDK11.
I have two Java files in the current folder, that are supposed to run together to be a JavaFX application.
One of them is called `Main.java` and runs the main window. Another is `Alert.java`, and is supposed to run an alternate window which is an alert type.
Now, I ran the following command:

```
javac -cp "c:\projects\java\currentProject" --module-path "c:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml Alert.java Main.java
```

While `Alert.java` compiled just fine, `Main.java` could not import the Alert class and gave an error on "import Alert". I tried "import Alert.Alert" and "import currentProject.Alert" but still, it didn't work.
Also, I declared package "package currentProject" at the start of each file and it still gave an error.

What am I supposed to do to get it running? I already failed on installing JavaFX on all available IDEs, so I'm not going to use an IDE other than Atom. But how do I compile it properly?

more info -

file structure:

c->projects->java->economicManager->( Alert.java ,Main.java, financialManager.fxml, alert.fxml, Alert.class, Alert$Controller.class, Main.class [previously compiled version])

Alert.java:

```
package financialManager;

import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Parent;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import java.util.Map;

public class Alert {

    public Stage stage;
    private Controler_Class controler;

    public Alert(Parent root) {

        Controler_Class clas = new Controler_Class(root);
        this.controler = clas;

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.setTitle("financial report");
        stage.setScene(scene);

        this.stage = stage;
        stage.showAndWait();
    }

    private class Controler_Class{

        Parent root;

        public Controler_Class(Parent root){

        }
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
package financialManager;

import Alert;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Parent;

import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import java.util.Map;

public class Main extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{

        final int width = 300;
        final int height = 450;

        stage.setTitle("hello mofos");

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("financialManager.fxml"));

        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, width, height);

        Map<String, Object> mapper = loader.getNamespace();
        AnchorPane pane = (AnchorPane) mapper.get("splitpane1_anchorpane");

        if(pane != null)
            SplitPane.setResizableWithParent(pane, false);
        else
            System.out.println("it's null you idiot!");

        Button btn = (Button) mapper.get("economicReport");

        btn.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {

            FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("alert.fxml"));
            Parent parent = loader2.load();
            Alert alert = new Alert(parent);
        });

        /*
        ChangeListener<Number> stageSizeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                pane.setDividerPositions(0.20219435736677116);

        stage.widthProperty().addListener(stageSizeListener);
        stage.heightProperty().addListener(stageSizeListener);
        */

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe show your directory structure, as well as your source code?

Comment: added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are importing the **Alert** class wrongly. Your package is **financialManager**, so you should use it in the import line like this:

```
import financialManager.Alert;
```

About your issues with IDEs, I made JavaFX work fine with Eclipse and IntelliJ on OpenJDK 11 without any issues a few days ago - For OpenJDK you will need [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/), and if you are interesting in some reading, [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/the-future-of-javafx-and-other-java-client-roadmap-updates) is the link from Oracle's blog on their plans for JavaFX.

Good luck!